# Each_with_index method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to ruby and I'm learning about loops right now. I'm using the each_with_index method to return the value and position of the element in a new array. Here, I created a method (called add_value_and_index) that goes through the each_with_index method for it to return the value and position in a new array (new_array)

```
def add_value_and_index(array)
  new_array = []
  new_array = array.each_with_index do |element, index|
    p "#{element} is a position #{index}"
  end
  new_array
end
```

I'm getting "ExpectationsNotMet" error in the RSPEC, what is missing in the code above for this to pass the test? Here is the specs for this:

```
describe '#add_value_and_index' do
  it "returns a new array composed of the value + index of each element in the former" do
    expect( add_value_and_index([2,1,0]) ).to eq([2,2,2])
  end
end
```

And the error that I'm getting:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError

expected: [2, 2, 2]
     got: [2, 1, 0]

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: It would help if you added the failing test.

Comment: Yes that would help. Your method looks fine, if "putsing" the element and their position is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. Here it is: 
`describe '#add_value_and_index' do
  it "returns a new array composed of the value + index of each element in the former" do
    expect( add_value_and_index([2,1,0]) ).to eq([2,2,2])
  end
end`

Comment: `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError

expected: [2, 2, 2]
     got: [2, 1, 0]

(compared using ==)

exercise_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>`

Comment: Sylvee, Cysanfar does not "see" it partly because they are probably looking in question for the test. Do not post code updates in the comments. I edited your question to show the rspec test. It should show up shortly. In the future always edit your question rather than post code in the comments.

Comment: Why are you expecting `add_value_and_index` to equal `[2,2,2]`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sum the elements and their indexes in order for it to pass your test:

```
def add_value_and_index(array)
  new_array = []
  array.each_with_index do |element, index|
    p "#{element} is a position #{index}"
    new_array << element + index
  end
  new_array
end
```

Another way to do it is using `map`:

```
def add_value_and_index(array)
  array.map.with_index do |element, index|
    element + index
  end
end

add_value_and_index [2, 1, 0] 
# => [2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: this is because `#each` returns self which should be mentioned in your answer.